# Some cardinals/ordinals Arithmetic

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

I am having trouble grasping ideas for the following three problems (and I am unsure whether the third condition even holds).
For arbitrary ordinals $\alpha$, $\beta$,

(Edit: on the LHS the operations are ordinal arithmetic, and the order relation between ordinals is given using Cartesian product of two sets, and giving it anti-lexicographical order)

1. $\operatorname {card}(\alpha+\beta) = \operatorname {card}(\alpha)+\operatorname {card}(\beta)$
2. $\operatorname {card}(\alpha\beta) = (\operatorname {card}(\alpha))(\operatorname {card}(\beta))$
3. $\operatorname {card}(\alpha^\beta) = \operatorname {card}(\alpha)^{\operatorname {card}(\beta)}$

Cardinal number is defined as the minimal ordinal that is equipotent to a set $X$ and equality condition for cardinals is as follows: $$\beta \leq \alpha, \beta \approx \alpha \to \beta = \alpha$$

Do I need to find an explicit bijection between two sets having the speicified cardinalities? I feel like I am missing out on some important parts. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Generally, it's easier to use Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein to imply the existence of a bijection rather than construct it explicitly. I recommend this approach for all 3 problems.

Comment: @DonThousand Ah, so in either way, we do have to show by constructing some sort of functions. Does the last equation hold in general? Extremely confusing to think about examples/counterexamples especially with infinite cardinalities...

Comment: I can assure you that for this problem, there are no counterexamples. I'm not sure which equation you speak of

Comment: @DonThousand I was speaking of $\alpha^\beta$ case, but thank you anyways. I was having trouble showing the $\beta \leq \alpha$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are ordinals. Does using Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein theorem handle that as well?

Comment: Why are you showing $\beta\leq\alpha$?

Comment: @DonThousand That was the definition of the order relation between cardinal numbers, as the textbook I am referring to defines ordinals first and then uses it to define cardinal numbers.

Comment: I get that. Why are you trying to show that? How does it help you at all?

Comment: @DonThousand I was just not too sure where to start from, so I thought I might as well strictly follow the definition - maybe not.

Comment: Just use CSB...

Comment: How the proof of 1. and 2. proceed depends on your working definition of the ordinal arithmetic operations. It's possible to define them as the order types of the disjoint union and Cartesian product, respectively, with particular orderings; but that's less common than the usual transfinite recursions. If you can use the fact that they're equivalent, your job will be easier. For 3., it's enough to show that $\omega ^ {\omega}$ is countable (ordinal exponentiation), unlike $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: @BrianO Yes - the definition follows Cartesian product method. I will add that in too. And thank you for the counterexample!